# Weird Error on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap for a long time. I'm noticing a weird error today. I'm opening mozilla console and there at least hundred errors showing on twitter-bootsrap source. then I tried to insert bootsrap cdn, but still the same errors. Here is a list of some errors:

```
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-inner-spin-button'. 
Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.

Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found
'-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found
'-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'. 
Declaration dropped.


Expected end of value but found '\9 '.  Error in parsing value for
'width'.  Declaration dropped.

Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped.
```

Is there anything wrong with bootstrap?

Comment: look the source of whatever CSS is causing this. Most likely it's being generated wrong. the errors suggest you've got something like `foo { color: -webkit-focus-ring-color }`

Comment: no, there's nothing wrong, Bootstrap was always like that and Validator doesn't recognize vendor prefixes and some "edge" styling and elements. Bottom line is: Don't get too attached to W3 Validator, it's just a guidance, but many times you'll need non-valid results in order to actually make a page work. Like Bootstrap (and thousands or scripts) Edit: in your case, it's Mozilla console. It's obvious it will drop webkit prefixes

Comment: @Fabio That should probably be posted as an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Some CSS elements have not passed validation in Mozilla but is accepted in Chrome. The same case is with Opera, Safari, especially IE and other browsers. Each browser has different rules that must be followed. Bootstrap and every quality CSS must be adapted to all browsers in order to work correctly. Therefore, some of the elements you'll find in consoles as invalid but in every browser shows different errors.

W3 Validator is guide only, in reality, the story is quite different.