# Bootstrap 3.3.6 warnings and errors in bootstrap.min.css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been getting a lot of Bootstrap warnings/errors since yesterday. This wasn't happening two days ago so I'm not sure what is going on. Here are the warnings/errors:

```
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-inner-spin-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.min.css:5:1544
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-search-cancel-button'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.min.css:5:1778
Unknown property 'orphans'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:2691
Unknown property 'widows'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:2700
Unknown property '-moz-osx-font-smoothing'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:3676
Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:15709
Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:35740
Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:35987
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.min.css:5:36918
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.min.css:5:36966
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-expand'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. bootstrap.min.css:5:37018
Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio'. bootstrap.min.css:5:37352
Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:38465
Unknown property 'touch-action'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:45403
Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:45511
Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:45712
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:46058
Expected color but found 'solid\9 '.  Expected end of value but found 'solid\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'border-top'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:54984
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:56351
Expected color but found 'solid\9 '.  Expected end of value but found 'solid\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'border-bottom'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:56896
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:85087
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:85273
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:85992
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:86178
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:86618
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:86804
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:87250
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:87436
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:87880
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:88066
Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:88502
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:105745
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:105854
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:107063
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:107116
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:108266
Unknown property 'line-break'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:108303
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:108328
Unknown property 'line-break'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:110310
Expected media feature name but found 'transform-3d'. bootstrap.min.css:5:112148
Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-transform-3d'. bootstrap.min.css:5:112163
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:113485
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:113554
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:113641
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:113723
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:113900
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:114097
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:114184
Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:114266
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:114443
Expected 'none', URL, or filter function but found 'alpha('.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. bootstrap.min.css:5:114668
Expected color but found '#\30 00\9 '.  Error in parsing value for 'background-color'.  Declaration dropped.
```

I am using Firefox 47.0.1. If anyone can shed some light on this it would be appreciated! I am linking the css file like this (copied from the official Bootstrap download page):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this thread:

[Weird Error on bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415390/weird-error-on-bootstrap)

Apparently it's a Firefox issue, the errors don't appear in Chrome.