# JS code to conduct a YouTube search and return a JSON response to the console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, json

I'm writing an application using JS, JQuery, Bootstrap and HTML. The goal of the application is to conduct a YouTube search on a user-entered keyword and return a JSON response to the console providing details about the videos turned up in the search.

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EAyo3_zJj5c) tutorial, and at this point in the tutorial I should be able to see the JSON response in the console on running the code. However, when I run my code on Firefox I get the following errors:

> Error in parsing value for ‘-webkit-text-size-adjust’.  Declaration
> dropped. _reboot.scss:28:2 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element
> ‘focus-visible’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
> bootstrap.css:66 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-expand’.
> Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. _forms.scss:7 Unknown
> pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset
> ignored due to bad selector. _forms.scss:7 Unknown pseudo-class or
> pseudo-element ‘-ms-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad
> selector. _forms.scss:7 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element
> ‘-ms-value’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. _forms.scss:71
> Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-value’.  Ruleset ignored
> due to bad selector. _custom-forms.scss:220 Unknown pseudo-class or
> pseudo-element ‘-ms-expand’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
> _custom-forms.scss:220 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-thumb’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
> _custom-forms.scss:382 Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. _custom-forms.scss:382 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-thumb’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
> _custom-forms.scss:382 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-thumb’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
> _custom-forms.scss:382 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-thumb’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
> _custom-forms.scss:382 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-track’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
> _custom-forms.scss:382 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-fill-lower’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
> _custom-forms.scss:382 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-fill-upper’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
> _custom-forms.scss:382 Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-thumb’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.
> _custom-forms.scss:382 Unknown property ‘orphans’.  Declaration dropped. _card.scss:252:4 Unknown property ‘widows’.  Declaration
> dropped. _card.scss:243 Unknown property ‘orphans’.  Declaration
> dropped. _print.scss:76:6 Unknown property ‘widows’.  Declaration
> dropped. _print.scss:79:4 Unknown property ‘size’.  Declaration
> dropped. _reboot.scss:46

​When I run it on Chromium, I get no errors, but also no console output.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var API_KEY = "AIzaSyCzpZZP564ykVqpun38mS0AbtR0cHoEYE0";

    $("#form").submit(function(event){

        event.preventDefault()

        alert("submitted")

        var search = $("#search").val()

        videoSearch(API_KEY,search,10)
    })

    function videoSearch(key,search,maxResults){

        $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=" + key
            + "&type=video&part=snippet&maxResults=" + maxResults + "&q=" 
            + search, function(data){
                console.log(data)
            })
    }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
    <title>YouTube Video Search</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search">
                
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Search">
                
            </div>
            
        </form id="form">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div id="videos">

            </div>  
        </div>  
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="youtube.js"></script>
</html>
```

I did some research and I suspect the errors in Firefox are partly due to browser peculiarities. However, I couldn't get the desired result in Chromium either, which makes me think there must be more to the problem. I can't use Chrome to check because my computer doesn't support Chrome. I would really appreciate any help figuring out what the issue is here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 3.3.6 warnings and errors in bootstrap.min.css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536775/bootstrap-3-3-6-warnings-and-errors-in-bootstrap-min-css)

Comment: `</form id="form">` <-- the id must be placed to the start tag, not the end tag

Comment: Oh wow that was dumb of me, thanks so much! It works now.

Answer (score 0):

As Guy Incognito pointed out, "</form id="form"> <-- the id must be placed to the start tag, not the end tag". This resolved the issue.