# Errors when booting Angular 2/4 application

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

When my Angular app boots (this is from the **ng serve** server) the web console is loading up with lots of error messages starting with the following:

```
GET 
http://localhost:4200/ [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/styles.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 1ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 4ms]
GET 
http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 4ms]
Error in parsing value for ‘-webkit-text-size-adjust’.  Declaration dropped.  localhost:4200:12:28
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-inner-spin-button’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  localhost:4200:207:17
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-search-cancel-button’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  localhost:4200:217:17
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-file-upload-button’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  localhost:4200:222:2
Unknown property ‘orphans’.  Declaration dropped.  localhost:4200:288:11
Unknown property ‘widows’.  Declaration dropped.  localhost:4200:289:10
Expected color but found ‘auto’.  Expected color but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Expected end of value but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.
(( several more pages of errors ))
```

After that the application itself actually works.  I am using Bootstrap 4 which also seems to work but I think these error messages are related to that.

How do I go about finding what is wrong and how to fix it?

The **package.json** is as follows:

```
$ cat package.json 
{
  "name": "cytable",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

The **.angular-cli.json** file has the following in it, edited down for length:

```
$ cat .angular-cli.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  ...
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
    ...
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

which refers to the src/style.css file, which has the reference to **bootstrap** in it like this:

```
$ cat src/styles.css 
/*@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";*/

@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Clearly something has gone wrong with the assembly of **main.bundle.js** (or before).

Any pointers much appreciated.

UPDATE:   Apparently this is a long-standing problem between [Bootstrap and Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415390/weird-error-on-bootstrap).  I replicated this error among different versions of Bootstrap and also verified the errors do not come up under Safari.   So I'm going to drop this for now.

Comment: what package are you using for bootstrap?  (could you post your package.json?)

Comment: @snorkpete OK I just did that.  I'm so new to this that I didn't even think to look there so you have already helped me up the learning curve.

Comment: okay, so you're using raw bootstrap (not any angular-bootstrap libraries). did you just add the bootstrap css to your index.html?  or did you include it in the styles portion of your `.angular-cli.json`?  (might make sense to post that as well for extra clarity)

Comment: @snorkpete Did that. OK so in the process of walking through this I have a much better understanding of how it works but not where it is going wrong.  Is there a special version of bootstrap meant just for Angular?

Comment: Since you are not using any angular-bootstrap integration projects (there are 2 i know of: `ngx-bootstrap` & `ng-boostrap`, but probably a lot more in reality), let's try to take the build system out of it and just include the bootstrap css as a link tag in your index.html (and remove the import)

Comment: Your problem seems to be css related only, so let's see if we just use the bootstrap css directly if you see any errors.

Comment: @snorkpete I did that and I still get the same errors.  The difference is that the Firefox inspector can give me a link straight to the line(s) that caused the error.  It starts with line 12 of bootstrap.css (v4.0.0-alpha.6) where it is trying to style html with -webkit-tex-size-adjust to 100%.  I don't get it.

Comment: Looks like a problem with bootstrap itself