# Bootstrap/Datatables CSS shows in chrome but not firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

having a problem getting CSS to show in firefox. I have a bootstrap site with datatables and all is fine and dandy in chrome but a lot of the CSS is missing in firefox, and the datatables don't show at all. In the developer console for firefox I get a lot of "declaration dropped' which I'm assuming is affecting my output. Is three a setting I'm missing on my page that allows firefox to interpret things correctly?

```
Error in parsing value for ‘-webkit-text-size-adjust’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:132
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-inner-spin-button’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bootstrap.min.css:5:1544
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-search-cancel-button’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bootstrap.min.css:5:1778
Unknown property ‘orphans’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:2691
Unknown property ‘widows’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:2700
Unknown property ‘-moz-osx-font-smoothing’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:3676
Expected color but found ‘auto’.  Expected color but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Expected end of value but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:15709
Error in parsing value for ‘margin-top’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:35740
Expected color but found ‘auto’.  Expected color but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Expected end of value but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:35987
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bootstrap.min.css:5:36918
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-webkit-input-placeholder’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bootstrap.min.css:5:36966
Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element ‘-ms-expand’.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector.  bootstrap.min.css:5:37018
Expected media feature name but found ‘-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio’.  bootstrap.min.css:5:37352
Error in parsing value for ‘margin-top’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:38465
Unknown property ‘user-select’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:45511
Expected color but found ‘auto’.  Expected color but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Expected end of value but found ‘-webkit-focus-ring-color’.  Error in parsing value for ‘outline’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:45712
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:46058
Expected color but found ‘solid\9 ’.  Expected end of value but found ‘solid\9 ’.  Error in parsing value for ‘border-top’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:54984
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:56351
Expected color but found ‘solid\9 ’.  Expected end of value but found ‘solid\9 ’.  Error in parsing value for ‘border-bottom’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:56896
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:85273
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:86178
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:86804
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:87436
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:88066
Unknown property ‘zoom’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:88502
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:105745
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:105854
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:107063
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:107116
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:108266
Unknown property ‘line-break’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:108303
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:108328
Unknown property ‘line-break’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:110310
Expected media feature name but found ‘transform-3d’.  bootstrap.min.css:5:112148
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:113485
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:113641
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:113900
Error in parsing value for ‘background-image’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:114184
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:114443
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘alpha(’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:114668
Expected color but found ‘#\30 00\9 ’.  Error in parsing value for ‘background-color’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap.min.css:5:115617
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  metisMenu.min.css:10:299
Error in parsing value for ‘width’.  Declaration dropped.  timeline.css:153:15
Error in parsing value for ‘width’.  Declaration dropped.  timeline.css:154:15
Unknown property ‘user-select’.  Declaration dropped.  bootstrap-datepicker3.css:83:13
Unknown property ‘-moz-osx-font-smoothing’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:4:594
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:4:1615
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:4:1778
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:4:1944
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.  font-awesome.min.css:4:2115
Expected ‘none’, URL, or filter function but found ‘progid’.  Error in parsing value for ‘filter’.  Declaration dropped.
```

edit: since it was asked for here is my header, it's just a standard bootstrap implementation.

```
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>IMS</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
<link href="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Timeline CSS -->
<link href="../dist/css/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Touchspin CSS -->
<link href="../dist/css/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link href="../bower_components/datatables-plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- DataTables Responsive CSS -->
<link href="../bower_components/datatables-responsive/css/responsive.dataTables.scss" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Datepicker3 CSS -->
<link href="../dist/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
<link href="../bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- TypeAhead CSS -->
<link href="../dist/css/typeaheadjs.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom Fonts -->
<link href="../bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link href="../dist/css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!-- jQuery -->
<!-- <script src="../bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script> -->
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
<script src="../bower_components/raphael/raphael-min.js"></script>
<script src="../bower_components/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/morris-data.js"></script>

<!-- Touchspin JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.js"></script>

<!-- DatePicker3 JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

<!-- Typeahead JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/typeahead.js"></script>

<!-- Bloodhound JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/bloodhound.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="../dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
<script src="../dist/js/ioma.js"></script>
```

edit: added chromegodo and fireboxbad. and on second look it looks like my one monitor is so old it isn't showing greys at all, I just saw that bootstrap shows up just fine but its now just the datatables not working. [image: firefox bad]
[image: chrome good]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Weird Error on bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415390/weird-error-on-bootstrap)

Comment: Some CSS properties are for specific browsers and aren't supposed to render in Firefox (like anything starting with `-ms` or `-webkit`). You should still be seeing _something,_ but without seeing your code in action we can't guess what.

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38536775/bootstrap-3-3-6-warnings-and-errors-in-bootstrap-min-css

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try putting some moz as an alternative to webkit in the CSS to give the browser a different read option
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-moz-appearance